# How to make a button inactive until I enter text in a JavaFX TextField?

Tags: java

I have a TextField and a Button. I want the button to be inactive until I enter text in the TextField

Code is TextField:

```
  <TextField fx:id="queueName" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="218.0" promptText="Введите очередь для подключения">
```

Code is Button:

```
<Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="46.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#connectQueue" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="169.0" text="Подключиться к очереди">
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the disable property of the button to whether the text field is empty in your java code. Something like this:

```
BooleanBinding isTextFieldEmpty = textField.textProperty().isEmpty();
button.disableProperty().bind(isTextFieldEmpty);
```

Comment: Where do I put it, I don't understand. I need to make the button initially inactive, and if you enter text, it becomes active. I don't understand which method or class to add your code to